# Where are my asp.net website compiled assembly files stored on my computer?

Tags: asp.net

My website is a "website" type, not a "web application" type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files will be at the end of this path somewhere. You may need to choose a different .NET version. In the temporary files folder you will find a gfolder for your project/solution.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Comment: Hi thanks.That where I thought the native code was stored. So where are the native machine code stored then?

Comment: The version folder you should choose is based on the version of the compiler you are using. For example, .NET 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 projects all use the 2.0 compiler. If you're running on a 64-bit machine, you will find an additional Framework64 folder with the same CLR version folders that will also have temporary assembly files.

Comment: @user370401 - native code is never stored by .NET. The assemblies in the temp folder are MSIL.

Comment: Hi Philip, thanks for the info. Why would .Net JIT compile the IL assembly everytime instead of using a native code? In "Pro ASP.NET 3.5 inC# 2008" the author vaguely mentioned about there is a native code. Based on what I understand there is no need to JIT compile the IL code as long as the hardware environment is not changed, because the JIT compilation method is mainly used to optimise the native code in relation to the hardware environment. I would be verysurprised if it has to be comiled every time since the cost would be huge

Comment: The point to note here is that the JIT compiler can compile MSIL to native code in the time it takes to read the MSIL from disk. So it has no cost. It is therefore never persisted. Although it is held in memory as long as it is needed. MSIL is compiled on a method by method basis. So a 2GB MSIL file which you need to call one three line method on will only JIT compile the three lines.

Answer (score 3):

By default they are located in %Windows Install Folder%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

It's possible to force the temp path to a specific location by a property to the compilation tag in the web.config.

```
<compilation tempDirectory=“E:\ASP.Net Temporary Folder\” debug=“false“>
```

Source: http://syedgakbar.wordpress.com/2007/11/10/changing-aspnet-temporary-files-folder/ for more.

Answer (score 2):

Technically there is no native code because when a web site is built using asp.net it gets run through the JIT so it creates these temporary files, I don't think you'll find dll's or exe's if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: The MSIL assemblies are created and stored in the temp folder. In fact there are two copies. The assemblies currently in use and the most recently compiled versions waiting to be shadow copied. The output from the JIT compiler is never stored.